# DtypeWarning: Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate a large amount of CSV files. I keep getting the dtype/memory warning in my terminal. Any ideas as to how to fix this, since it's not in a DataFrame? Thanks!

My code is as follows

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.csv')]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
print(all_filenames)

combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Did you try doing what the warning suggested?

Comment: Hi, beginner here, I don’t know where I’d specify it. I tried adding the low memory option to the combined csv command but it doesn’t make a difference

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add it to `pd.read_csv`, but you probably should be specifying dtypes, I'm pretty sure `low_memory` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try!